# iOS4: UIImagePickerController behaving weirdly when presented modally

Tags: iphone, ios4, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to present a `UIImagePickerController` from a `UITableViewController` subclass using the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
if(library)
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
else
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

If I create a brand new project and throw this code in, it works absolutely fine. However, in this project, for some reason, the `UIImagePickerController`'s view appears as a blank white screen if I try to show the Photo Library, or shows the camera view but with no camera controls if I try to show the Camera.

Is there anything in a `UITableViewController` subclass that would be causing this? I get complaints about two-stage animations as well, but from what I've been able to find, this is an issue with Apple's code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, changing the `PRODUCT_NAME` in the Info.plist (something which I was going to do anyway but hadn't gotten around to until just now) fixed this issue. I have absolutely no idea why, but I'm going to assume it was some obscure bug in the iPhone SDK.